# What does this symbol "I" mean in a manga? What is its usage?

Tags: manga, kana

I saw in a manga **ミIナト** meaning *minato* a name but I don't know what the character between **ミ** and **ナ** means and the usage of it

and theres another one too **おまさてI** and theres like 3 lines below it's written downwards

I'm not sure if its a mi katakana or what[image]

and what does that **S** like symbol mean?
[image]

Comment: the line just means it’s read みいな. it shows an over exaggerated pronunciation. kind of like saying “eeeveryone?”

Comment: the 2nd one is お待たせしました literally meaning “i made you wait”. it’s usually said regardless of how long you’ve perhaps been made to wait by servers etc. it essentially means “i’m sorry you had to wait”. here again the vertical line suggests an exaggerated pronunciation.

Comment: Are you familiar with ー in things like コーヒー?

Answer (score 5):

- This vertical bar is a long vowel marker written vertically. Here, it just indicates "Minato" is pronounced with some accent. In English it would be "Mii-nato!" or something. Maybe the speaker said "Minato" slowly and loudly to draw attention, or maybe the speaker is not a native Japanese speaker. You can see the same symbol after おまたせ.
- These S-like symbols are "wave dashes". They are usually used in place of long vowel markers in manga, light novels, etc (See [What is the difference between the wave dash 〜 and long vowel marker ー when marking long vowels?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11660/5010)). However in this context, they are probably used in place of ellipsis (`･･･`) used to indicate the speaker is at a loss of words.
- By the way, this `っ` is another way of indicating the speaker cannot say something. See: [What does ending a statement with 「っ」signify when coupled with 「・・・」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5867/5010) and [What does the little っ (tsu) signify when at the end of a word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1457/5010)

Comment: very nice and thorough answer and the links you provided were very helpful. thank you.

Comment: 「………」だと思考停止してしまって無言の感じですが、「～～～」だと感情が昂りすぎて（あわてすぎて）声が出ないという感じがしますね

Answer (score 0):

こんばんは、that symbol is the same as this one: ー, but when the text is written verticaly, it turns into that. The function of this symbol is to prolong the sound of vowel. In your case ミーナト　can be read as miinato, but if it didn't had this symbol, like  ミナト, it would be read as minato.

Hope you understand, Nickzus.

Comment: do you know what the つ is about?  inly reason i didn’t write up an answer is due to that detail.

Comment: Little つ makes the sound stronger, it gives you a little pause before pronouncing the hiragana. You can see if often translated to something like that: あった　－＞　atta. In that romaji, that the "t" sound is stronger. In comparasion, the "ー" just makes the PREVIOUS hiragana vowel sound longer.

Comment: that’s not the sort of つ i was referring to. i’m familiar with what you’re talking about. what i’m not familiar with is the ~~~~~つ in the second frame.

Comment: "～" that character indicates, also, the lenghtening of a pronunciation, in that case, you can see it as a pause (as you cannot see any hiragana previous to it) followed by a "tsu" sound. That can be interpreted as a expression of scord, that sound can be seen in many anime as something like "Tss.."